# Prevent user to change Select option if response value meet condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent change to 'Present' if previous (echo) value 'Repeater' but user can set 'Drop' by confirming alert. I'm not an expert just learning so please correct me is any mistake.
this is my try:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="status" class="form-control" id="status" required onchange="myFunction();">
        <option value="Repeater">Repeater</option>
        <option value="Present">Present</option>
        <option value="Repeater">Repeater</option>
        <option value="Drop">Drop</option>
        </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#status').change(function(){
if($('#status option:eq(0)').val() === "Repeater"){
if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to destroy these country branches?"));
$('#status option:eq(3)').prop('selected', true);
}else{
$('#status option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
$("#status option[value='Present']").prop('disabled',true);
$('#status option:eq(2)').prop('disabled',true);
$("#plnt").hide();
}
});
</script>
```

If Index 0 have 'Repeater' then index 1 & 2 disable user can select only index 3 if user confirm change.

Comment: Post a usable example, not PHP but HTML output.

Comment: So what is your question?